# API REST Node.js App- MySQL Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, api

Me encuentro en el desarrollo de un microservicio el cual va a estar expuesto mediante una API REST. Este servicio está pensado para que reciba un GRAN volumen de usuarios, por lo que me preocupa que algunas tablas en la base de datos (MYSQL) agoten las Primary Keys designadas mediante AUTO_INCREMENT y la integridad de los datos.
Por otro lado, también me preocupa aquellas PK que no se puedan reutilizar, por ejemplo, si alguien borra la tabla con id 2 y existe 1 y 3 pasaría a 4 directamente. Es por esto que me interesaría saber algún approach eficiente para la generación de PKs, teniendo en cuenta que va a recibir una gran cantidad de inserciones.

Gracias